# In which points of $\mathbb R$ is the distribution of $\mu = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n} \delta_{\phi(n)}$ not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am thinking about the following:

> Let $\phi : \mathbb N \to \mathbb Q$ be a bijection and define a measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ by $\mu := \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n} \delta_{\phi(n)}$, where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac measure for given $x$. In which points of $\mathbb R$ is the distribution of $\mu$ not continuous?

Remark: For a given measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ with $\mu(\mathbb R) < \infty$, $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) := \mu((-\infty, x])$ is called the distribution of $\mu$.

The distribution $f$ of $\mu$ is right-side continuous.

$f$ is non-decreasing $\Rightarrow \lim_{x \uparrow p} f(x)$ exists.

If we have specified $p$, we could take a suitable non-decreasing sequence $(x_n)$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = p$ and show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) \ne p$.

And does $\phi$ need to be bijective?

So far I have that
\begin{align*}
f(p) = \mu((-\infty, p]) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n} \delta_{\phi(n)}((-\infty, p]).
\end{align*}
It would be nice, if I could compute the sum with the geometric formula, but I cannot say how large $n$ is, when I sum terms of zeros.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Edit:
Let $p$ be a point in the image of $\phi$, i.e. $p = \phi(m)$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$. Let $(x_j)$ be a monotone increasing sequence with $\lim_j x_j = p = \phi(m)$. Then
\begin{align*}
f(p) - \lim_j f(x_j) &= \lim_j\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n} \{\delta_{\phi(n)}((-\infty, \phi(m)]) - \delta_{\phi(n)}((-\infty, x_j])\}.
\end{align*}
Now 
\begin{align*}
\delta_{\phi(n)}((-\infty, \phi(m)]) - \delta_{\phi(n)}((-\infty, x_j]) = \delta_{\phi(n)}((x_j, \phi(m)]).
\end{align*}
There is at least one $n$, namely $n = m$, for which the term above does not vanish, thus
\begin{align*}
f(p) - \lim_j f(x_j) \ge \lim_j 2^{-m} = 2^{-m} > 0.
\end{align*}
Is this correct?

Comment: It's easy to show that the distribution of $\mu$ is not continuous at any point in the image of $\phi$ (and this doesn't depend on whether $\phi$ is bijective, or even that its range is contained in $\Bbb Q$). I think it's also not hard to show that the distribution is continuous everywhere else. (I don't understand what you're asking at the end, about the geometric formula. In general I don't think this distribution is easy to actually compute.)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I need to define the sequence, which approximates a given point in the image of $\varphi$? Probably it is easy, but I can't see it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the sequence, which approximates a given point in the image of $\phi$".

Comment: The idea was that I take a sequence $x_n$ which converges to a point $p$ in the image of $\varphi$, but $\lim f(x_n) \ne f(p)$. This would mean, that $f$ is not continuous in $p$. Sorry for the misleading sentence.

Comment: Ah ok. In this case, any sequence $x_n$ tending to $p$ from the left will reveal the lack of continuity. (Indeed, $f$ is an increasing function, so any discontinuity must be a jump discontinuity, which means that it won't take carefully chosen sequences to reveal the discontinuity.)

Comment: Please see my edit :)

Comment: looks fine to me!